# How to make my random questions not repeat?

Tags: java, android, random

I'm learning to program, i need my quiz random questions not to be repeated.
Java - Android Studio

##my code:

```
quizModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
random = new Random();
    
getQuizQuestion(quizModalArrayList);
currentPos = random.nextInt(quizModalArrayList.size());
    
private void getQuizQuestion(ArrayList<QuizModal> quizModalArrayList) {
    
quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal(R.drawable.prolinfocitos, "b", "b", "c", "dd","b"));
quizModalArrayList.add(new QuizModal(R.drawable.prolinfocitos, "b", "b", "c", "dd","b"));
```

[quizModal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ekK.png)
there are more lines of code, but I believe they are unrelated to the problem.

any help?
Thanks

Comment: Would a random shuffle help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: In order to prevent questions to show up mutliple times, you need to track which questions already have been seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rethink your approach. The easiest solution: you define the complete random order upfront. Meaning: you first load all your questions into your base list, in whatever order. Then you create a copy of that list, and **shuffle** that copy (using that built in function: [Collections.shuffle(List)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)). And that shuffled list copy is what your user gets to see. And then you just iterate that list bottom to top.

Comment: Thanks for the "reminder", wanted to edit the answer in that respect, and forgot about it ;-)

Comment: Get all questions at the start and create a copy -> shuffle copy and show a question to the user -> remove the seen question from copy -> shuffle again and show the question. repeat until you reach the end of copied list.